# Reading Unicode characters from command line arguments using boost::program_options in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, command-line-arguments, boost-program-options

I have several Windows applications that read a file path from command-line arguments. Everything works flawlessly, except when passing paths with non-ANSI characters. I expected this, but don't know how to deal with it. Probably an entry-level question but that is driving me crazy.

My current code looks like:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    namespace po = boost::program_options;

    po::options_description po_desc("Allowed options");
    po_desc.add_options()
        ("file", po::value<std::string>(), "path to file");

    po::variables_map po_vm;
    try {
        po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, po_desc), po_vm);
        po::notify(po_vm);
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << po_desc << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    const std::string file_path = po_vm["file"].as<std::string>();

    // ...
}
```

I've found that if I replace the type of `file_path` from `std::string` to `boost::filesystem::path`, some paths are now read. I don't know exactly why but can deduce that it has to be with a translation from the Latin1 charset.

For example, having following files:

```
malaga.txt
málaga.txt
mąlaga.txt
```

The first is always read correctly, while the second one fails when using `std::string file_path` but not `boost::filesystem::path file_path`. The third one always fails.

I've tried switching the main function to `int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv)` and using `std::wstring` for the argument type, but it is not compatible with `boost::program_options` parser.

How can I correctly read such Unicode file names?

Comment: Have you read __Unicode Support__ https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#id-1.3.32.6.8

Comment: Maybe you need to [`chcp 65001`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=chcp+65001) first?

Comment: Setting the console codepage via chcp.com has nothing do with this. The native command line in Windows is Unicode (UTF-16LE). The issue is that the C runtime's `main` entry point parses the ANSI encoding of the command line from `GetCommandLineA` instead of the Unicode command line from `GetCommandLineW`. The non-standard `wmain` entry point is based on the native Unicode command line. The `wchar_t` strings could then be encoded as UTF-8 via `WideCharToMultiByte` if the application needs byte strings.

Comment: Thanks every one, your comments have been very useful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Thanks for everyone contributing with their comments, thanks to them I managed to solved my problem.*

### TL;DR

Here the fixed code:

```
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[]) { // <<<
    namespace po = boost::program_options;

    po::options_description po_desc("Allowed options");
    po_desc.add_options()
        ("file", po::wvalue<std::wstring>(), "path to file") // <<<
        ("ansi", po::value<std::string>(), "an ANSI string")
        ;

    po::variables_map po_vm;
    try {
        po::store(po::wcommand_line_parser(argc, argv) // <<<
                    .options(po_desc)
                    .run(),
                  po_vm);
        po::notify(po_vm);
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << po_desc << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    const boost::filesystem::path file_path = po_vm["file"].as<std::wstring>(); // <<<

    // ...
}
```

## Explanation

First, switch to `wmain` and `wchar_t* argv`: as mentioned by [@erik-sun](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59143297/1485885#comment104516258_59143297), it is necessary to switch the entry point to an Unicode aware function. Important note: it is possible to use `int main(int, wchar_t*)` (in the sense it will compile) but it won't receive arguments with the correct codification and parser will fail, you have to use `wmain`.

Then, the [Unicode support link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#id-1.3.32.6.8) provided by [@richard-critten](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59143297/1485885#comment104514390_59143297) was very useful for understanding the compilation errors:

- use `boost::program_options::wvalue` when the type is wide-char. The internal implementation uses a string stream: the default one only works with 8-bits chars.
- use `boost::program_options::wcommand_line_parser` to accept `wchar_t*` arguments. Unfortunately, this class doesn't have an all-in-one constructor and you must use the *long* form for parsing the command line.
- finally, retrieve the value as `std::wstring` when needed.

I've extended the code snippet to show it is still compatible with `std::string` inputs.

## Side note

My complete solution requires instantiating a Qt `QApplication` at some point. `QApplication` constructor is incompatible with the wide-char `argv`. As no command-line interaction is needed with the Qt part (everything is processed long before by Boost), it can be re-written to receiv fake arguments:

```
int fake_argc = 1;
char* fake_argv[] = {"AplicationName"};
QApplication a(fake_argc, fake_argv);
```